# Selecting lowest integer value (non unique) for each table entry that shares the same column value

Tags: mysql

I have a single database table 'Accomodation' that lists information of hotel/B&B suites with the city they are located in, the price and an ID for each suite that functions as the primary key.

It looks similar to this:

```
id     | city       | Price
ams001 | Amsterdam  | 160
ams011 | Amsterdam  | 120
par004 | Paris      | 90
par006 | Paris      | 120
rom005 | Rome       | 130
rom015 | Rome       | 130
```

I want to list all information of the cheapest accomodation for each city, however if two records both share the same lowest price I want to display both of these.

The result should look something like this:

```
ams011 | Amsterdam  | 120
par004 | Paris      | 90
rom005 | Rome       | 130
rom015 | Rome       | 130
```

I have tried using

```
SELECT * FROM accomodation
WHERE price IN (SELECT MIN(price) FROM accomodation GROUP BY city);
```

However this will produce a table like this

```
ams011 | Amsterdam  | 120
par004 | Paris      | 90
par006 | Paris      | 120
rom005 | Rome       | 130
rom015 | Rome       | 130
```

Since the 120 price is the cheapest for Amsterdam it will show up at Paris too.
If I add a group by statement at the end, outside of the subquery like this:

```
SELECT * FROM accomodation
WHERE price IN (SELECT MIN(price) FROM accomodation GROUP BY city)
GROUP BY city;
```

It will fail to display lowest values that are identical and I'm left with a table like this:

```
ams011 | Amsterdam  | 120
par004 | Paris      | 90
rom015 | Rome       | 130
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First GROUP BY city to get the min price for each city and then join to the table:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM accomodation a INNER JOIN (
  SELECT city, MIN(price) minprice
  FROM accomodation
  GROUP BY city
) g ON g.city = a.city AND g.minprice = a.price
```